# Productivity of SharePoint server

Tags: sharepoint, sql-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I had an installation of SharePoint Server 2013 and SQL Server 2012 on the one Server. Time of opening of SP page is large (about 1 min in local network). Server have 12 GB of RAM, but only 1,2 GB is standby and 100 MB is free. Is it normal situation if SharePoint is used as knowledge base with volume of documentation about 500 Mb with full text search? And how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all running SharePoint Server with SQL server should be used only in development/testing environment. For production use, you should always have two separate servers for SharePoint and for SQL server.

'Problem' with SQL server is that it caches everything that is read from database to memory for faster access. That is the reason why it seems that your server does not have enough memory. SQL server is expected to use all available memory.

If you really need to have both products on the same server it should have at least 20 GB of RAM:

- 12 GB is minimum for production SharePoint server
- 8 GB is minimum for production SQL server

You should also set maximum memory for that SQL instance so it won't consume all available memory. Do not forget that OS itself needs some RAM.
[image: SQL max memory]

> **Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint 2013**
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-0#hardware-requirementsweb-servers-application-servers-and-single-server-installations